# How to initialize MediaPlayer in android without an R.raw file

Tags: android, audio, media-player

How do I initialize MediaPlayer in Android without an R.raw or some kind of file?

If I don`t initialize MediaPlayer with some file I will get a null pointer exception at runtime.  But when the program is started there is no file path to use because the user has not yet pressed a button to select the mp3 file from the SD card.

When initialzing the Media Player there is another probem. It only takes an R.raw type file, not the path of a file from the SD card.  And if I don't have any file in the R.raw directory then I can`t initialize with a file.  It appears that you need an audio file in the local R.raw folder to do this.

```
 Mediaplayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample_music);
```

There is a method called "setDataSource" that allows me to set the path of the file, however I have to initialize the MediaPlayer first.

```
  player.setDataSource(selectedAudioPath);
```

Any other way to initialize MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filepath);
```

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me and the code below works as well:

```
Mediaplayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(File.getAbsolutePath()));
```